# Post image to Facebook Page Timeline via Graph API

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api

I would like to post a photo to the Timeline of a Facebook Page via Graph API. My setup is node-based and written in coffeescript. My current implementation is this (error handling ommited):

```
sendImageToFacebookTimeline = (user, message, imageURL, callback)->
  url     = "https://graph.facebook.com/#{pageID}/photos"
  params  =
    access_token: user.accessToken
    url: imageURL
    message: message

  request.post({url: url, qs: params}, (err, res, body)->
    body = JSON.parse(body)
    callback(body.id)
  )
```

This succesfully posts the photo to my Page. But instead of appearing on the timeline it appears in the "Photos of PAGE".

How can I post to the Timeline?

**EDIT:**
I found out that by posting to /page_id/feed with option "picture" you can send a photo to Timeline. This shows up the same way as og:image and the view is similar to a link.

**EDIT 2:**
If you upload to a album, it will show up on Timeline. I have created an album and trying to post to it. But the API doesn't seem to accept URL for source when posting to /album_id/photos.

Comment: So the solution is to post into a album instead? It's showing "Posted 3 Image" etc , I want every single one to display

Comment: When I last tested this (22.8.2013) the photos were shown on the timeline even if posted to an album. Please elaborate your situation if this doesn't satisfy your appetite for knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## To post to own Timeline you need to acquire Page access token from */me/accounts* and not by getting a user token or exchanging token for a long term token.

With that and album ID you can post to an album, which shows up on the Timeline.